# When is the convex envelope lower semicontinuous for an infinite dimensional space?

Tags: convex-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

Let $X$ be a infinite-dimensional Hausdorff real topological vector space and $f:X\to[-\infty, \infty]$ be a proper function. Define the convex envelope of $f$ to be the largest convex minorant of $f$.

**My question:** are there any results in convex analysis which give sufficient conditions for the convex envelope of $f$ to be lower semicontinuous?

In a finite dimensional space, there are broad cases where convexity implies continuity and hence lower semicontinuity. For example, **Proposition 2.17** of Barbu's "Convexity and Optimization in Banach Spaces" states that
if $X$ be a finite dimensional Hausdorff topological vector space and $f:X\to[-\infty,\infty]$ is a proper convex function, then $f$ is continuous on the interior of $\text{Dom}(f)$. This is statement that applies to all convex functions, but I only need a statement for the convex envelope.

Are there any analogous results for similar (yet infinite-dimensional) spaces? I am willing to assume $X$ is a Banach or even Hilbert Space if needed.

Comment: Do you want to have conditions on $f$? For arbitrary $f$, this already fails in $\mathbb R$, consider $f = \delta_{(0,1)}$. It is already convex, but not lsc at $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Hi, to confirm, does $\delta_{(0,1)}$ mean a function that is $+\infty$ on $(0,1)$ and $0$ elsewhere? I don't mind conditions on $f$ but would like to them to be very general if possible. Happy to restrict $f$ to being real-valued though